# How can I insert in database values from dropdown list based on a relationship between 2 tables? I am using ASP.NET c# Entity framework, Code first

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am not talking about the id of the element in the list, but the id of it from a table if the value is in another table. E.g I have a FullName and an ID in one table and I have the same ID and some other stuff in another table(one to zero or one relationship). I have bound the FullName to a dropdown list control,but when saving,I need to refer to it's ID from the table, not the string value.

Comment: Return the Id when you bind FullName, and reference that.. either in a label or however you want to do it. But show some code so we can better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place something in a drop down list, you can place the ID in the value field and something else as a text, for example :

```
ddlCategorie.DataTextField = "Texte";
ddlCategorie.DataValueField = "ID_GLOBAL";
ddlCategorie.DataSource = db.GLOBAL.Where(t => t.DATE_FIN > dt).OrderByDescending(t => t.ID_GLOBAL).ToList();
ddlCategorie.DataBind();
```

As you see, I already placed the reel database value "ID" of the object inside the value field of the drop down list. So I can immediately retrieve is ID by doing :

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCategorie.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: I have tried the same thing,but when I associate the id for my entity with the selected id, it's still 0.

Comment: Are you sure the name is correct ? it has to be the same exact same name than what is in your database, ho and, watch out for multiples postback, it can ruin everything. The if(IsPostBack == false) can save you from a lot of work, make sure you understand that thing.

Comment: Yes,I have this all. I don't know if my Visual Studio gone wild or something, but it's working today. I have used pretty much the same approach, with a minor difference. For DataSource I used db.<NameOfTheTable>.ToList().